# Find new inserted words in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, diff, difflib

I want to find the new words which are inserted into a text file using Python. For example:

```
Old: He is a new employee here.
New: He was a new, employee there.
```

I want this list of words as output: `['was', ',' ,'there']`

I used `difflib` but it gives me the diff in a bad formatted way using `'+', '-' and '?'`. I would have to parse the output to find the new words. Is there an easy way to get this done in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

```
import re

# create a regular expression object
regex = re.compile(r'(?:\b\w{1,}\b)|,')

# the inputs
old = "He is a new employee here."
new = "He was a new, employee there."

# creating lists of the words (or commas) in each sentence
old_words = re.findall(regex, old)
new_words = re.findall(regex, new)

# generate a list of words from new_words if it isn't in the old words
# also checking for words that previously existed but are then added
word_differences = []
for word in new_words:
    if word in old_words:
        old_words.remove(word)
    else:
        word_differences.append(word)

# print it out to verify
print word_differences
```

*Note that if you want to add other punctuation such as a bang or semi-colon, you must add it to the regular expression definition. Right now, it only checks for words or commas.*

Comment: But, if the old text contained the word "there" in some other place, would it return this word?

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. The idea remains the same, but there's a simple fix for that degenerative case. I'll edit to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

I used Google Diff-Patch-Match. It works fine.